# Trying to run webapplication on Tomcat Server but cannot run

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm using do post method as my method.I am trying to deploy a servlet on Tomcat 6.0.37. Tomcat is also up. I have put the project inside the webapps folder. As when I open the localhost URL I get the home page of Tomcat. When I fill up the welcome JSP form and hit the submit button I get the following error:

> The requested resource (/Airlines/ChooseAirline.do) is not available.

I searched but could not find anything which could help me. I'm trying simple to get a message after hitting the submit button on JSP and check whether it comes to Servlet or not.

My web.xml is as follows-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>Airlines</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>ChooseAirline.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet>
              <servlet-name>ChooseAirline</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>com.chooseairline.ChooseAirlines</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>ChooseAirline</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/ChooseAirline.do</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

In my servlet Im only trying to print hello world as the output on the webpage. My servlet code is as follows-

```
    package com.chooseairline;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.*;

    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    public class ChooseAirlines extends HttpServlet{
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException
        {
            String requestDropDown = request.getParameter("dropDownSelectClass");
            System.out.println("the value here is "+requestDropDown);
             response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out;
                try {
                    out = response.getWriter();
                     out.println("<html>");
                        out.println("<head>");
                        out.println("<title>Hello World!</title>");
                        out.println("</head>");
                        out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
                        out.println("</body>");
                        out.println("</html>");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
    }
```

I'm new to Servlet development and Apache server. I tried many times but getting the same problem.

I'm also including my JSP along with this . Please check it-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Generated by Pure CSS Menu.com : Free CSS Drop Down Menu Generator</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Online CSS Menu Maker. Create No-Javascript, 100% CSS Dropdown Menu in seconds! Horizontal css menu & Vertical css menu." />
</head>
<form id="airLineform" name="airLineform" action="ChooseAirline.do" method="POST">
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" background="AirlineImage.jpg" onload="disableFields()" >



<!-- Start PureCSSMenu.com STYLE -->
<style>
body {

  padding-left: 17em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
#pcm{display:none;}
fieldset {
  background-color: #333333;
  padding-left: 2em;
   padding-right: 2em;
  border-color:#cccccc #111111 #111111 #cccccc;
  #color: #111111;
  font:normal 12px Trebuchet MS, Tahoma;
  color: #cccccc;
}
#dropDownSelectClass {
    padding: 5px;
    #color:#333333;
    font:normal 12px Trebuchet MS, Tahoma;
   background-color:  #cccccc;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

}
 ul.pureCssMenu ul{display:none}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>ul{display:block}
ul.pureCssMenu ul{position: absolute;left:-1px;top:98%;}
ul.pureCssMenu ul ul{position: absolute;left:98%;top:-2px;} 


ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color:#333333;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color:#cccccc #111111 #111111 #cccccc;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
?
ul.pureCssMenu table {border-collapse:collapse}ul.pureCssMenu {
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
    float: left;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul{
#   width:155.4px;
}
#ul.pureCssMenu li{
#   display:block;
#   margin:2px 0px 0px 2px;
#   font-size:0px;
#}
#ul.pureCssMenu a:active, ul.pureCssMenu a:focus {
#outline-style:none;
#}
ul.pureCssMenu a, ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover, ul.pureCssMenu li.sep a:hover {
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:#333333;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#333333;
    border-style:solid;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 80px;
    _padding-left:0;
    font:normal 12px Trebuchet MS,Tahoma;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:default;
}

#ul.pureCssMenu span{
#   overflow:hidden;
#}
ul.pureCssMenu li {
    float:left;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul li {
    float:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul a {
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#ul.pureCssMenu li.sep{
#   text-align:left;
#   padding:0px;
#   line-height:0;
#   height:100%;
#}
#ul.pureCssMenu li.sep span{
#   float:none; padding-right:0;
#   width:3px;
#   height:100%;
#   display:inline-block;
#   background-color:#cccccc #111111 #111111 #cccccc;   background-image:none;}
#ul.pureCssMenu ul li.sep span{
#   width:100%;
#   height:3px;
#}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover{
    position:relative;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>a{
#   background-color:#377D9F;
#   border-color:#377D9F;
#   border-style:solid;
#   font:normal 12px Trebuchet MS, Tahoma;
#   color: #FFFFFF;
#   text-decoration:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li a:hover{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#377D9F;
    border-color:#377D9F;
    border-style:solid;
    font:normal 12px Trebuchet MS, Tahoma;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a {
#   color: #666 !important;
}
#ul.pureCssMenu img {
#border: none;float:left;_float:none;margin-right:2px;width:16px;
#height:16px;
#}
ul.pureCssMenu ul img {
width:16px;
height:16px;
}
#ul.pureCssMenu img.over{display:none}
#ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover img.over{display:none !important}
#ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover img.def {display:inline !important}
#ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a img.def  {display:none}
#ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a img.over {display:inline}
#ul.pureCssMenu a:hover img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul #img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover #img.over{display:inline}
#ul.pureCssMenu a:hover img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul #img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def{display:none}
#ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover ul,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul{display:block}
#ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul ul,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover ul ul{display:none}
ul.pureCssMenu span{
    display:block;
    background-image:url(./images/arr_white.gif);
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-right:12px;}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>a>span{ background-image:url(./images/arrv_white.gif);
}
ul.pureCssMenu a:hover span{    _background-image:url(./images/arrv_white.gif)}
ul.pureCssMenu ul span,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover table span{background-image:url(./images/arr_white.gif)}
</style>
<!-- End PureCSSMenu.com STYLE -->



<!-- Start PureCSSMenu.com MENU -->
<div text-align: center >
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<ul class="pureCssMenu pureCssMenum">
    <li class="pureCssMenui" text-align: center><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">About ChooseAirline</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Aircrafts</a><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>Atrributes</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <ul class="pureCssMenum">
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Value For Money</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Seat Comfort</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Staff Service</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Catering</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Entertainment</a></li>

    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</tr>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<tr>
<td></td><td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td>
<fieldset>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<p>
<label>Select the Class</label>&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp
 <select id="dropDownSelectClass" name="dropDownSelectClass" onchange="enabalingFieldSet()">
 <option value="defaulOption">Select a Class</option>
  <option value="firstClass">First Class</option>
  <option value="business">Business</option>
  <option value="economy">Economy</option>
</select> <br> <br><br>
<div id="radioButtonsDiv" >
<label>Value for Money</label>
&nbsp<input type="radio" name="ValForMoney" value="good">Good<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="ValForMoney" value="medium">Medium
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="ValForMoney" value="bad">Bad
<br>
<br>
<label>Set the preference for Value for Money</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefValueForMoney" value="first">First
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefValueForMoney" value="second">Second
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefValueForMoney" value="third">Third
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefValueForMoney" value="fourth">Fourth
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefValueForMoney" value="five">Five
<br>
 <br>
 <br>
<label>Seat Comfort&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="seatComf" value="good">Good<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="seatComf" value="medium">Medium
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="seatComf" value="bad">Bad
<br>
<br>
<label>Set the preference for Seat Comfort</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefSeatComfort" value="first">First
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefSeatComfort" value="second">Second
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefSeatComfort" value="third">Third
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefSeatComfort" value="fourth">Fourth
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefSeatComfort" value="five">Five
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label>Staff Service</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="staffService" value="good">Good<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="staffService" value="medium">Medium
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="staffService" value="bad">Bad
<br>
<br>
<label>Set the preference for Staff Service</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefStaffService" value="first">First
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefStaffService" value="second">Second
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefStaffService" value="third">Third
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefStaffService" value="fourth">Fourth
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefStaffService" value="five">Five
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label>Catering&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="catering" value="good">Good<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="catering" value="medium">Medium
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="catering" value="bad">Bad
<br>
<br>
<label>Set the preference for Catering</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="preCatering" value="first">First
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="preCatering" value="second">Second
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="preCatering" value="third">Third
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="preCatering" value="fourth">Fourth
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="preCatering" value="five">Five
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label>Entertainment</label>
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="entertainment" value="good">Good<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="entertainment" value="medium">Medium
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="entertainment" value="bad">Bad
<br>
<br>
<label>Set the preference for Entertainment</label>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefEntertainment" value="first">First
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefEntertainment" value="second">Second
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefEntertainment" value="third">Third
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefEntertainment" value="fourth">Fourth
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="prefEntertainment" value="five">Five
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</p>
</td>
</fieldset>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>
<!-- End PureCSSMenu.com MENU -->



<!-- (c) 2009, PureCSSMenu.com -->

<script>
function enabalingFieldSet(){
    //alert('entered here');
    //stylecolor= document.getElementById('dropDownSelectClass').selected;
    //alert('entered here22 ');
    var e = document.getElementById("dropDownSelectClass");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (strUser=='business' || strUser=='economy' || strUser=='firstClass'){
        //alert('the selected value here is '+strUser);
        enableFields();
    }
    else{
    //alert('entered here222'+document.getElementById("radioButtonsDiv"));
     document.getElementById("airLineform").reset();
            disableFields();
    }
                   // document.getElementById("foo").style.display="block";
      //          }else{
                //    document.getElementById("foo").style.display="none";
        //        } 
  //  document.getElementById('dropDownSelectClass').style.color="black";
}
function disableFields()
{
    var prefValueForMoneyradios = document.airLineform.prefValueForMoney;
    var prefValLength=prefValueForMoneyradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefValLength; i++) 
    {
        prefValueForMoneyradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    var ValForMoneyradios = document.airLineform.ValForMoney;
    //var prefValMoney=ValForMoneyradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<ValForMoneyradios.length; i++) 
    {
        ValForMoneyradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    var seatComfradios = document.airLineform.seatComf;
    //var prefValLength=seatComfradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<seatComfradios.length; i++) 
    {
        seatComfradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var prefSeatComfortradios = document.airLineform.prefSeatComfort;
    //var prefValLength=prefSeatComfortradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefSeatComfortradios.length; i++) 
    {
        prefSeatComfortradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var staffServiceradios = document.airLineform.staffService;
    //var prefValLength=staffServiceradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<staffServiceradios.length; i++) 
    {
        staffServiceradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var prefStaffServiceradios = document.airLineform.prefStaffService;
    //var prefValLength=prefStaffServiceradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefStaffServiceradios.length; i++) 
    {
        prefStaffServiceradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var cateringradios = document.airLineform.catering;
    //var prefValLength=cateringradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<cateringradios.length; i++) 
    {
        cateringradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var preCateringradios = document.airLineform.preCatering;
    //var prefValLength=preCateringradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<preCateringradios.length; i++) 
    {
        preCateringradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var entertainmentradios = document.airLineform.entertainment;
    //var prefValLength=entertainment.length;
    for (var i=0; i<entertainment.length; i++) 
    {
        entertainment[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    var prefEntertainmentradios = document.airLineform.prefEntertainment;
    //var prefValLength=prefEntertainmentradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefEntertainmentradios.length; i++) 
    {
        prefEntertainmentradios[i].disabled = true;
    } 
    //
    //
    //document.airLineform.Date1.disabled=true
}
function enableFields()
{

    var prefValueForMoneyradios = document.airLineform.prefValueForMoney;
    var prefValLength=prefValueForMoneyradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefValLength; i++) 
    {
        prefValueForMoneyradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    var ValForMoneyradios = document.airLineform.ValForMoney;
    //var prefValMoney=ValForMoneyradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<ValForMoneyradios.length; i++) 
    {
        ValForMoneyradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    var seatComfradios = document.airLineform.seatComf;
    //var prefValLength=seatComfradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<seatComfradios.length; i++) 
    {
        seatComfradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var prefSeatComfortradios = document.airLineform.prefSeatComfort;
    //var prefValLength=prefSeatComfortradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefSeatComfortradios.length; i++) 
    {
        prefSeatComfortradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var staffServiceradios = document.airLineform.staffService;
    //var prefValLength=staffServiceradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<staffServiceradios.length; i++) 
    {
        staffServiceradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var prefStaffServiceradios = document.airLineform.prefStaffService;
    //var prefValLength=prefStaffServiceradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefStaffServiceradios.length; i++) 
    {
        prefStaffServiceradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var cateringradios = document.airLineform.catering;
    //var prefValLength=cateringradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<cateringradios.length; i++) 
    {
        cateringradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var preCateringradios = document.airLineform.preCatering;
    //var prefValLength=preCateringradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<preCateringradios.length; i++) 
    {
        preCateringradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var entertainmentradios = document.airLineform.entertainment;
    //var prefValLength=entertainment.length;
    for (var i=0; i<entertainment.length; i++) 
    {
        entertainment[i].disabled = false;
    } 
    //
    var prefEntertainmentradios = document.airLineform.prefEntertainment;
    //var prefValLength=prefEntertainmentradios.length;
    for (var i=0; i<prefEntertainmentradios.length; i++) 
    {
        prefEntertainmentradios[i].disabled = false;
    } 


    //
    //
    //document.airLineform.Date1.disabled=true*/
}
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Hii.. My JSP is huge which is as follows-

Comment: I have done that...Thanks alot...

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I copy pasted your code and it works for me. What does your project directory structure look like and do you have any errors in your startup logs?

Comment: Hi.thanks for the reply.. there is nothing in the logs.... My project directory is as follows-Inside webapps folder I have got my application folder named Airlines and inside that my JSP, and WEB_INF folder. Inside WEB_INF folder I have got folders classes which contians servlet class file and libs folder and also the web.xml file

Comment: The servlet is under `WEB-INF/classes/com/chooseairline`?

Comment: Yes it is ....The servlet is under WEB-INF/classes/com/chooseairline

Comment: Can you please share your project directory structure....

Comment: I've got the same as you. I recommend you put a no arg constructor in your servlet class with a log statement and then add `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startupt>` to your `<servlet>` element. Restart the application and see if the log statement is printed.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to put logs.Are you telling me to use log4j jars.. I tried System.out.println but nothing is getting printed on the console of the tomcat server.... Please advice.....

Comment: Just a simple `System.out.println("whatever")` will be fine. Don't forget to add the `<load-on-startup>` bit.

Comment: No ... its not getting printed....

Comment: Go into `tomcat-install/logs/` and check the contents of `catalina.out`.

Comment: Yes I checked... there is nothing in there.... no logs.....

Comment: Thanks alot Sotirios for your help and patience... I did and it was happening due to the temps of apache tomcat server

Answer (score -1):

in your JSP try the following.

```
action="/ChooseAirline.do"
```

if it does not work

try

```
action="../ChooseAirline.do"
```

Comment: Please explain what these changes would accomplish.